# MySQL STR_TO_DATE function not work for time

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want only time to compare with another time string, so i am using `STR_TO_DATE` function to convert my time string to date time format

Below statement works fine for me, so i think MySQL don't have any problem

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('26/04/2011', '%d/%m/%Y');
```

But i don't know why below one is not working for me

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11:59:59','%h:%i:%s');
```

Above statement always return NULL when i run in SQL Console of PhpMyAdmin

Comment: works for me...

Comment: Doc says it all: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date

Comment: Try doing this: `SET sql_mode = '';`

Comment: @AnandRockzz i tried your suggestions but that will give me result in 24 Hours. I mean if i enter STR_TO_DATE('10:30 PM', '%h:%i %p') this will give me 22:30:00 . Why i am not getting PM in result. Does i missed something?

Comment: Could you please post the results of the following:
`show variables like 'date%format';`
`show variables like 'time%format';`

Comment: ..in case, you wanna restore your sql_mode, `SET 'sql_mode', 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'`

Comment: @AnandRockzz  Result of `show variables like 'date%format';` is
`date_format  %Y-%m-%d`
`datetime_format  %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s`

Comment: And result of  `show variables like 'time%format';` is
`time_format  %H:%i:%s`

Comment: The sql query: SELECT STR_TO_DATE('11:59:59','%h:%i:%s');  worked for me. What version of mysql server are you using ?

Comment: @NadirLatif  MySql server version is  5.7.16

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch  phpMyAdmin Version is: 4.5.4

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed because of the SQL mode `NO_ZERO_DATE`. You should have seen that when Anand Rockzz linked to the manual, but that link is only half of the explanation. As of MySQL 5.7.4, the setting is deprecated. In your first example, you're setting a date; in the second one, `NO_ZERO_DATE` causes the return of NULL because you're not specifying a date. Starting with 5.7.8, `NO_ZERO_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` have been included with the default sql_mode value. According to [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-changes), it appears as if the deprecation and removal has been partially reverted (starting with 5.7.8), so you may be able to explicitly set this in your `my.cnf` (or per-session).

You should also refer to the manual regarding the [NO_ZERO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) directive.

Comment: Only knowing I've a problem with my 'NO_ZERO_DATE' and tried fixing it resolved my issue. Thanks.