# STR_TO_DATE() returning NULL for some TIME values

Tags: mysql, datetime, time

In one of my projects, I was using the function `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert a string into a date value based on the fmt format string. For example to convert a string into a DATE value:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('21-5-2013','%d-%m-%Y'); // returns 2013-05-21
```

But when I went to convert a time string into a TIME value, I get some strange behaviors:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('203005','%h%i%s'); // returns null
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('19:30:05','%h:%i:%s'); // returns null
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('113005','%h%i%s'); // returns 11:30:05
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01:30:05','%h:%i:%s'); // returns 01:30:05
```

One of the answers I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41373337/7673764) in StackOverflow is that:

> This is indeed because of the SQL mode NO_ZERO_DATE.

But I'm still intrigued by the behavior of the function. You could check easily what I'm talking about by following this [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/query/mysql-str_to_date/#4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the format you are setting, it recognises the time from 0-12, not 0-23. It should be

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('203005','%H%i%s');
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('19:30:05','%H:%i:%s');
```

Check the following link with the list of all available time and date formats.
https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date.php

Comment: I have copy/pasted `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('19:30:05','%H:%i:%s');` as proposed by you and I still get `null` any idea why? It does work for strings with date values but not with time values

Comment: You can check on w3schools that it works. [https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_str_to_date](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_str_to_date) 
You can also see all the different ways you can write this from the link below [http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date). Check if in your format something is not passed correctly

Comment: %h actually only recognizes 1-12 (not 0-12)... so you would get NULL for 00:00. Changing to %H fixes that!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up contat-ing the date doing something like this to avoid having a `null`.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(
      concat('01/01/2018', ' ', '19:30:05'),
      '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'
   ),
   '%H:%i:%s'
);
```