# How to Search Records In MySQL Using StartTime(varchar) And EndTime(varchar)?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Here I have some records, I want to search for records from 8:30 AM to 9:30 AM.

[image: Screenshot of phpmyadmin]

I tried these query but not working:

```sql
select * from table_name where '8:30 AM' BETWEEN start_time and end_time OR '9:30 AM' BETWEEN start_time and end_time

select *
from time_test
where STR_TO_DATE(start_time, '%h:%i %p') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('08:30 AM', '%h:%i %p') AND STR_TO_DATE('09:30 AM', '%h:%i %p')
    OR STR_TO_DATE(end_time, '%h:%i %p') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('08:30 AM', '%h:%i %p') AND STR_TO_DATE('09:30 AM', '%h:%i %p')
```

Here is table sql :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `time_test`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `time_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `start_time` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `end_time` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `time_test` (`id`, `name`, `start_time`, `end_time`) VALUES
(1, 'R1', '8:00 AM', '9:00 AM'),
(2, 'R2', '9:00 AM', '10:00 AM'),
(3, 'R1', '8:00', '9:00'),
(4, 'R2', '9:00', '10:00'),
(5, 'R2', '1:00 PM ', '2:00 PM'),
(6, 'R2', '13:00 ', '14:00'),
(7, 'R1', '8:00 PM', '9:00 PM'),
(8, 'R1', '8:30 AM', '9:30 AM');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function. In my example using `DATETIME`. Can try with your `database` records.

```
SELECT `yourdatabase`
  FROM `yourtable`
 WHERE DATETIME(`yourcolumn`) = '2019-06-17 08:30'
```

However, for better performance you could use..

```
  WHERE `yourcolumn` 
BETWEEN '2019-06-17 08:30:00'
    AND '2019-06-17 09:30:00'
```

You can check [HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) for details or read [THIS](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/mysql/how-to-query-date-and-time-in-mysql/).

Comment: I tried DATETIME function in PHP MySQL it's not working. And I tried this query also
"SELECT * FROM `time_test` WHERE `start_time` BETWEEN '2019-06-17 08:30:00' AND '2019-06-17 09:30:00' " it's also not working.

Comment: In my code, using `DATETIME`, in your case you using `TIME`. Please, read my detail answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. I tried this query "select *
from time_test
where TIME(start_time) BETWEEN TIME('07:00 AM') AND TIME('10:00 AM')
    AND TIME(end_time) BETWEEN TIME('07:00 AM') AND TIME('10:00 AM')" but its not working only with  AM PM.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to minutes and add where conditions: 
View example :

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table 
WHERE 
    ( 
        HOUR(start_time ) * 60 + MINUTE(start_time) >= HOUR('8:30 AM' ) * 60 + MINUTE('8:30 AM')
        AND 
        HOUR(start_time ) * 60 + MINUTE(start_time) <= HOUR('9:30 AM' ) * 60 + MINUTE('9:30 AM')
    )
    OR 
    ( 
        HOUR(end_time ) * 60 + MINUTE(end_time) >= HOUR('8:30 AM' ) * 60 + MINUTE('8:30 AM')
        AND 
        HOUR(end_time) * 60 + MINUTE(end_time) <= HOUR('9:30 AM' ) * 60 + MINUTE('9:30 AM')
    )
```

Comment: Hi AU Nguyen, thank you so much for the help, I tried this above query but should not show these records which have start_time " 8:00 PM" and end_time "9:00 PM". It's fetching these records also.

Comment: Because your string query used "Or", so I used "OR" in my query. You can replace "OR" with "AND" to get records with start_time and end_time between '8:30 AM' - '9:30 AM'

Comment: I tried this query but still not working in AM PM Cases.

Comment: I tried this query "SELECT *
FROM time_test 
WHERE 
    ( 
        HOUR(start_time ) * 60 + MINUTE(start_time) >= HOUR('7:00 AM' ) * 60 + MINUTE('7:00 AM')
        AND 
        HOUR(start_time ) * 60 + MINUTE(start_time) <= HOUR('10:30 AM' ) * 60 + MINUTE('10:30 AM')
    )
    AND 
    ( 
        HOUR(end_time ) * 60 + MINUTE(end_time) >= HOUR('7:00 AM' ) * 60 + MINUTE('7:00 AM')
        AND 
        HOUR(end_time) * 60 + MINUTE(end_time) <= HOUR('10:30 AM' ) * 60 + MINUTE('10:30 AM')
    )" But it's also returning PM records.

Comment: @Deepak, you can use STR_TO_DATE to convert 24h before get hour. SELECT  HOUR(STR_TO_DATE('08:35 PM', '%l:%i %p'))

Comment: Hi @Au Naguyen thanks, But the main problem I am facing convert 12 hour format time to 24 hour format str_to_date function is returning null means that this function is not working.

Comment: I have google about time conversion and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986058/mysql-12-hr-to-24-hr-time-conversion      and tried "select  time_format(str_to_date('01:56:39 PM','%r'),'%T')" but this is also not working I think this is not working because of str_to_date() function returning null.

Answer (score 0):

since you're not storing the data as `DATETIME` format, to select a records ranged limited to only within `8:30` to `9:30`, you could use `STR_TO_DATE` :

```sql
select *
from table_name
where (STR_TO_DATE(start_time, '%h:%i %p') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('08:30 AM', '%h:%i %p') AND STR_TO_DATE('09:30 AM', '%h:%i %p'))
    AND (STR_TO_DATE(end_time, '%h:%i %p') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('08:30 AM', '%h:%i %p') AND STR_TO_DATE('09:30 AM', '%h:%i %p'))
```

To also select a records ranged outside the `8:30` and `9:30` range :

```sql
select *
from table_name
where (STR_TO_DATE(start_time, '%h:%i %p') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('08:30 AM', '%h:%i %p') AND STR_TO_DATE('09:30 AM', '%h:%i %p'))
    OR (STR_TO_DATE(end_time, '%h:%i %p') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('08:30 AM', '%h:%i %p') AND STR_TO_DATE('09:30 AM', '%h:%i %p'))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help but above query not working properly with AM PM  records result.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my codes, using `STR_TO_DATE` instead

Comment: thanks for help, But str_to_date returning null and query is not working.

Comment: I've updated the query, and I also have tested using your table sql and it is work (returns rows). What is returning null?

Comment: Hmm, if it's working for you then why not working in my system. I tried this query in PHPMyAdmin but not working. what could be the reason?

Comment: [here](https://prntscr.com/pb6xy5) is the result of the 1st query and [here](https://prntscr.com/pb6yq0) is the result of the 2nd query, are you sure you didn't miss anything?

Comment: Hi big thanks for the help, I have found a solution, why this query was not working in my system. to understand problem go to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318941/mysql-str-to-date-function-not-work-for-time   So for this I will have to change SQL mode in MySQL